# How do I fix the error "Did you really think you are allowed to see that"

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am fresher in cakephp. For my current project, I am using `CakePHP skeleton app`. Everything going fine. But when I am creating new controller for admin panel then it showing this message `Did you really think you are allowed to see that?`. Someone please help me.

I am showing my codes below:

Route:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
     // Other routes are here.
     $routes->connect('/sections', ['controller' => 'Sections', 'action' =>'index']);
}
```

SectionsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

    use App\Controller\AppController;

    class SectionsController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        echo "I am for sections page";
    }

}
```

This controller is locate in `src\Controller\Admin` folder

Below is my error message.

[image]

Comment: are you logged in?

Comment: Yes I am logged in. without logged in it redirect's to login page.

Comment: Look at the stacktrace, you are **un*authorized***, not to be confused with **un*authenticated***. Check/show what you're doing **[authorization wise](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#authorization)**.

Answer (score 3):

probably this would be the solution.

```
use Cake\Event\Event;
class YourController extends AppController
{
     public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
     {
         parent::beforeFilter($event);        
         $this->Auth->allow('index');
     }
}
```

Comment: This would be temporary solutions. Solution will be [Authorization](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#authorization) which @ndm says